# Iterating in a date column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL rookie here.

I have this table:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+
| business_id |     date_creation     |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| '3610'      | '2012-08-19 07:43:05' |
| '5020'      | '2012-08-18 03:38:51' |
| '5020'      | '2012-08-18 03:38:51' |
| '9491'      | '2017-08-18 06:52:52' |
| '10389'     | '2012-08-18 07:08:50' |
| ...         |                       |
+-------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm getting that through this query:

```
SELECT
  citation.business_id,
  citation.date_creation
FROM citation,
     business
WHERE primary_activity_id = 850
AND business.id = citation.business_id;
```

However, I want to filter only the dates from the year 2017.

Comment: Hint:  `date_creation >= '2017-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your query like this:

```
SELECT
  citation.business_id,
  citation.date_created
FROM citation,
     business
WHERE primary_activity_id = 850
AND business.id = citation.business_id
AND YEAR(citation.date_created) >= 2017;
```

Comment: I don't think we advocate implicit JOINs around here

Comment: Is the year function slower than an explicit range or does the optimizer take care of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `AND` clause to compare the date column value to a date literal.

```
SELECT
  citation.business_id,
  citation.date_created
FROM citation,
     business
WHERE primary_activity_id = 850
AND business.id = citation.business_id
AND citation.date_created >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer tarking.  I have added some text explaining your response. Please adjust it further if necessary.  Do we also need `AND citation.date_created <= '2018-01-01 00:00:00'`?

Comment: I am a beginner, I think it is not very necessary for the blogger's question

Comment: `filter only the dates from the year 2017` is what made me think you'd use need to limit it - regardless, looks like the accepted answer is shorter by using the YEAR function. Cheers.